# Windows 8 multi-monitor notification area

Tags: windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar, notification-area

Is there any way to allow the notification area to be displayed on both taskbars in a multimonitor configuration?

It's currently limited to only appearing on the primary monitor and there doesn't seem to be any GUI options to change this behaviour.

Comment: There are lots of multi-monitor programs around that provide this feature (although the good ones are all non-free).